# layout is broken when i turn of my personal hotspot

Tags: ios, iphone

My layout is broken when i turn off my personal hotspot , when my personal hotspot is on, it goes wel but the layout stays the same when my personal hotspot is turned off. Any suggestion pls.

Comment: You need to give more information. What layout? which device?

Answer (score 3):

When `personal-hotspot` is on, `notification` is called, catch it and change layout as you want

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(statusBarFrameWillChange)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

personal-hotspot is on , statusBar's height is 40

personal-hotspot is off , statusBar's height is 20

Comment: This shouldn't be needed. Handling the taller status bar is no different than dealing with using the app while on a phone call. A properly written UI will automatically adjust to change in height without the need to listen for this notification.

Comment: How so? If I am sliding an image down from the top using a constraint from the top of the image to the Top Layout Guide. When I set the constant to 0, the image is partially hidden when I go on a call.

Answer (score 0):

Add below Notification method in Appdelegate.m file and check whether status bar frame has been changed or not if so change your frame.

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame{

}

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help someone.

I saw the similar issue while working on an old application. it was without autolayouts and it has many subviews inside scrollview. Multiple classes view put on it. 
I realised the root cause. 
When hotspot is not enabled and suppose View controller view is set to origin (0,0). Now if you enable the hotspot. The status bar height changes to 40 and self.view origin shifts to  (0,20). So every subview frame if it is initialised with self.view.frame will shift 20 px downward. To fix it. i did not shuffle whole of the code. Rather, i placed the changes in

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews(){} /**method.
```

I explicitly set the subview to origin (0,0).
Then, It worked rather than by enabling any status bar change notifications.if your content is placed correctly. it will automatically adjust.